# Can't find PHP binary file

Tags: php, binaryfiles

Each time I save my `.php` file in Sublime this pops up:

> Can't find PHP binary file at { "php_bin":"/usr/local/bin/php" }

I've done everything I know, so far I'm doing research for the answer.

Comment: what do you get from typing `php -v` in the console/terminal ?

Comment: PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Feb  7 2017 16:18:37) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies


Is what i get

Answer (score 6):

For me it was phpfmt extention that could not find php.

In `Sublime Text > Preferences > Package Settings > phpfmt > Settings - Default` it showed:

```
{
"version": 4,
"php_bin":"/usr/bin/php",
"format_on_save":false,
"option": "value"
}
```

I did a `which php` in my terminal and it displayed
`/usr/local/bin/php`
So my php is not in /usr/bin/php

To change this I opened
`Sublime Text > Preferences > Package Settings > phpfmt > Settings - User`
to set my personal preferences.

```
{
"php_bin":"/usr/local/bin/php",
"format_on_save":true,
}
```

Saved that and t was fixed.
No more pop-up, and formatted on save.

Comment: Exactly the fix for me, except I'm on MacOS 13.4 (Ventura) which doesn't have a built-in PHP, so my path was `/opt/homebrew/bin/php`.

Comment: @DavidRhoden Sure, `which php` will tell you where your php is. With homebrew it can be in /opt/homebrew/bin/php ... today :) ... Another new issue can be that pmpfmt does not like your version of php. I think there is an update for ST4 php8.x

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have right path on php. To find out enter command line

```
which php
```

if the result is

```
/usr/bin/php
```

place the above path in the sublime configuration

Comment: You place, /usr/bin/php in the config ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, you can also run this to find any binaries called `php` in your system, even if it's outside $PATH:

`sudo find -type f -name php -executable -exec file -i '{}' \; | grep 'x-executable; charset=binary'`