# Sublime gives the error can't find php binary file at /usr/local/bin/php. What do I do if the php is in a docker container only?

Tags: php, docker, sublimetext

I'm using Docker with MacOS.

Every time I save a file in Sublime Text this appears

**Can't find PHP binary file at /usr/local/bin/php**

I previously made changes to block this but then on restarting Sublime I'm back to square one.

I have checked this [Can't find PHP binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401766/cant-find-php-binary-file) but I don't have a local php *(which php - php not found)*, it is located in a docker container:

`docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash`

inside the docker bash **which php**  gives **/usr/local/bin/php**

In this case how do I create a PATH in phpfmt to permanently stop the Sublime message?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with VSCode on Linux...

So, VSCode or SublimeText are looking for a local (i.e. outside the container) copy of PHP to run code against.

If our actual PHP is in a container, we need some means of "making it think" there is a local copy of PHP.

The first step is to create that "fake" local copy. So we create a file. it doesn't really matter where it is, but I keep it in my `~/bin` directory.

The second stage is to make that file actually act like it really is PHP. So we make the file executable and put the following script in it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
docker exec -it <container name> /usr/local/bin/php $@
```

With this script in place locally, we can do this in (e.g.) a terminal window:

```
/home/ME/bin/php --version
```

And, as long as the container is up, it should give us the PHP version.

Then in VSCode or Sublime, there's a config option somewhere that says "path to php" (or something like that) - I'm on VSCode, so you're on your own finding this option in Sublime Text.

And we make that config setting be `/home/ME/bin/php` or whereever else you put the local script.

You know have a local "fake" PHP that Sublime can run (as long as the container is up) using the "real" version of PHP that's on the container.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but you might need to walk me through that one.

Comment: @Martyn - I've edited my answer to be more of a "walk through".

Comment: Hi, sorry but I decided to remove phpfmt as a workaround, since webserver issues are not my strong point and they tend to be so time-consuming. I therefore can't acknowledge if this would work or not. Thank you for your time.